# How to assign string passed through a function call to a variable in c

Tags: c

```
void Somefunction(char title[]){
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //Assign title to newnode value
    newnode->data = ???????????
}

int main()
    char *Title[3] = {"my","cow","milk"};
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<sz;x++){
        Somefunction(Title[x]);
    }
}
```

Please help, i am new to c.

So Title[x] in this function call: Somefunction(Title[x]) carry the value: 'my' for first pass for instance.
In the function definition, how do i assign 'my' to newnode->data

Comment: if you want to store a string better to use 2d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to copy the string you have to give `data` it's place. i'm assuming your struct has a member called `data` and its `char*`.

you can do this:

```
size_t len_of_str = strlen(title);

newnode->data = (char *)malloc(len_of_str + 1);
if (NULL == newnode->data)
{
   return (NULL);
}

strncpy(newnode->data, title, len_of_str);
newnode->data[len_of_str] = '\0';
```

assuming your struct looks like this:

```
struct node{
    char *data;
    more members...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities which all make sense:

### newnode->data = title

Simply assign the string (the char pointer, the passed parameter) to the char pointer `data` in the new struct.

This assumes the strings stay where they are when they were defined in `main()`.

Output: the first line is the original string (pointer) Titles[0-3]. The following lines have the `newnode` pointer and its `data` pointer, plus content. See code at bottom.

```
0x5612be43a00e my 1 
0x5612bfc716b0 0x5612be43a00e my    /* a00e as original */
0x5612bfc716d0 0x5612be43a011 cow   /* originally contigous */
0x5612bfc716f0 0x5612be43a015 milk
```

### newnode->data = strdup(title);

This is like an extra malloc for the string. Makes sense if you have to copy the characters away fro where they are now.

```
0x55868f5e600e my 1 
0x55868fe1a6b0 0x55868fe1a6d0 my    /* besides malloced newnode */
0x55868fe1a6f0 0x55868fe1a710 cow  
0x55868fe1a730 0x55868fe1a750 milk
```

### strcpy(newnode->data, title);

This integrates the characters inte the newnode itself. But now it has to be `char data[6]`, not `char *data` in the struct. For this situation maybe a good idea, if the words are all that short and not repeating. Of course `6` is terribly low -- but it has to be fixed size.

```
0x561cadfc800e my 1 
0x561caee8c6b0 0x561caee8c6b8 my      /* inside the struct */
0x561caee8c6d0 0x561caee8c6d8 cow
0x561caee8c6f0 0x561caee8c6f8 milk
```

---

All three versions can be uncommented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Somefunction(char *title) {

    struct node {
        long something;
        //char *data; 
        char data[6];           /* for strcopy */
    } *newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);

    //newnode->data = strdup(title);
    //newnode->data = title;
    strcpy(newnode->data, title);
    printf("%p %p %s\n", newnode, newnode->data, newnode->data);



}

int main() {
    char *Titles[3] = {"my","cow","milk"};
    printf("%p %s %d \n", Titles[0], Titles[0], sizeof *Titles[0]);
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        Somefunction(Titles[x]);
    }
}
```

Even though - or because - the compiler magically stores the 3 arrays, their sizes seem lost (they have a terminator). `sizeod` returns either pointer size or char size, as shown.

Your strings are shorter than a pointer. So the `strcpy` version results in low and compact memory usage.